# natbib bst file with merge functionality

Tags: natbib

According to the documentation citations can be merged in natbib (several citations appear as one item in the bibliography). The different citations should be separated by semicolons, if the 'semicolon' option is used.

I have tried this with several bst files (including all revtex bst files), but the semicolon never appears. Can anyone point me to a bst file, where the merging fuctionality of natbib works as it should?

Answer (score 3):

In the natbib documentation it states:

> These functions are available only to numerical-mode citations, and
>   only when used parenthetically, similar to the restrictions on sort and
>   compress.
>
> They also require special .bst files, as provided for example by the
>   American Physical Society for their REVTEX class.

If I use the following file with a revtex4.1 bst file I get the right output:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[sort&compress,numbers,merge]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{Cundall-1979,
    author = {Cundall, P. A. and Strack, O. D. L.},
    title = {A discrete numerical model for granular assemblies},
    journal = {G\'eotechnique},
    year = {1979},
    volume = {29},
    pages = {47--65},
    number = {1}}
@ARTICLE{Haff-1986,
    author = {Haff, P. K. and Werner, B. T.},
    title = {Computer simulation of the mechanical sorting of grains},
    journal = {Powder Technology},
    year = {1986},
    volume = {48},
    pages = {239--245},
    number = {3}}
@ARTICLE{Jaeger-1996,
    author = {Jaeger, H. M. and Nagel, S. R.},
    title = {Granular solids, liquids, and gases},
    journal = {Reviews of Modern Physics},
    year = {1996},
    volume = {68},
    pages = {1259--1273},
    number = {4}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
In \citep{Cundall-1979, *Haff-1986, Jaeger-1996} and
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks Danie. I noticed that ubuntu's texlive package has a faulty natbib version from 2009. Everything works fine with the recent package from CTAN.